# Can no longer call methods on Javascript object after res.send with Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

#### Context and Design Overview

Im using a library called [Tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master) to load Tiff images on a webpage. I'm using the Library on the server and on the client. In my server I use the library to create a Tiff object from a Tiff file on the server. I then use **ExpressJS** to send the Tiff object to the client.

#### Problem

*Summary*: Can no longer use methods on object after sending an object to client using `res.send(object)` 
*More Info*:
From the server (in Node.js), when I call methods from the Tiff.js library on the Tiff object it works fine. Here you can you see that I've called some methods for information on the file and log them to the console.[image]
In the client, I use **AngularJS** to get the Tiff object. This seems to be successful since I can console log the object. But when I call a Tiff.js library method on the object it throws an error. Here you can see I logged the Tiff object and then tried to log the width of the Tiff object.
[image]
*Note*: I have checked to make sure that the Tiff.js file is correctly loaded client side.

#### Code

Server Controller

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Tiff = require('./tiff');
var filename = 'test.oct';
var tiff;

exports.loadOCTFile = function(req, res) {
    Tiff.initialize({
        TOTAL_MEMORY: 300000000
    });


    fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, filename), function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        tiff = new Tiff({
            buffer: data
        });

        console.log('width:', tiff.width());
        console.log('height:', tiff.height());
        console.log('currentDirectory:', tiff.currentDirectory());
        console.log('countDirectory:', tiff.countDirectory());
        tiff.setDirectory(0);
        res.send(tiff);
        tiff.close();
    });
};
```

Relevant Client JS inside of Angular Controller

```
$scope.getTest = function() {
    $http.get('/oct_analysis_open').success(
        function(tiff) {
            console.log(tiff);
            console.log('width:', tiff.width());
        });
};
```

I can post the Express routing if needed.

Comment: what IS `width` on the client if it is not a function?

Comment: if the object comes from ajax, there will never be any methods on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you receive the object as the payload of a response. This payload is then deserialized as an object, but it's just that, a **plain** object. You need to wrap the received `tiff` plain object again with the Tiff library if you want to call its methods on it.

The fact that you're using JS on both the client and the server means you can share some code, but it does not mean that the objects are shared: you're still using a client/server model and objects are passed from one side to the other after being serialized/deserialized to something (probably JSON) that contains the data and ONLY the data. Functions are not serialized.

Edit: You might want to try to send the data to the client, and on the client side recreate a Tiff object the way you do it on the server, using the data you received.

Comment: I see. It seems that process is too intensive to do client side since the browser ends up crashing when I try. This is why I want to do it on the server. Is there any other workaround? I want to display these images on the html.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. You might want to try saving the image somewhere reachable from the client and give it the url to the image, or you could save the image somewhere unreachable from outside and add a route with an action that returns the byte stream of the image that is being requested. Can I ask why TIFF?

Comment: Hey sorry I know this is a late response. Unfortunately I don't believe its possible to save the image using the Tiff.js library. Im using TIFF because its a popular format for medical images. Question: What about sending the object to client using something like Socket.io?

Comment: No matter how you send the object to the client, you'll only end up with the data. I strongly advise against attempting to serialize the object's methods to `eval` the on the other side as that poses a serious security threat (even more so if you're working with medical data). How about converting the TIFF data to PNG and sending that in a base64 encoded format to client? Do you need to have high-res images on the client for PACS-like usage?